# NextJS - React-Native monorepo with react-native-elements

Tags: node.js, react-native, webpack, next.js, monorepo

I'm trying to use react-native-elements in a react-native monorepo.
It works fine in the Native App, but not in the NextJS Application.

First, it compiles successfully:

```
> with-react-native-web@ dev <path>\WebApp
> next

ready - started server on http://localhost:3000
info  - automatically enabled Fast Refresh for 1 custom loader
info  - Using external babel configuration from <path>\WebApp\babel.config.js
event - compiled successfully
```

But when I try to access http://localhost:3000, it starts compiling again, but fails:

```
<path>\WebApp\node_modules\react-native-elements\src\index.js:7
import Button from './buttons/Button';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1001:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1049:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:791:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.react-native-elements (<path>\WebApp\.next\server\pages\_app.js:3783:18)
    at __webpack_require__ (<path>\WebApp\.next\server\pages\_app.js:23:31)
    at Module../pages/_app.js (<path>\WebApp\.next\server\pages\_app.js:3640:79)
```

I believe that the error might be in the next.config.js file:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  webpack: (config, { defaultLoaders }) => {
    config.resolve = {
      ...config.resolve,
      alias: {
        ...config.resolve.alias,
        'react-native': path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules', 'react-native-web'),
      },
      modules: [
        ...config.resolve.modules,
        path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
      ],
    }

    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.+(js|jsx)$/,
      use: defaultLoaders.babel,
      include: [
        path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'shared'),
        path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules', 'react-native-elements'),
        path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules', 'react-native-vector-icons'),
        path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules', 'react-native-ratings'),
      ],
    })

    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
      loader: "file-loader?name=/public/icons/[name].[ext]"
    })

    return config;
  }
}
```

Comment: got the same problem here

Comment: did you guys figure it out?

Comment: React Native packages that are used in web have to be transpiled first in Next Config. NextJS has special config for that.

Comment: That's true. We managed to used to transpile it first